# Is it possible to create sound focus in a room?

Tags: acoustics

Is it possible to create a place, where sound, produces by room's environment, is loud in one or several points, but barely audible in other parts of the room?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whispering_gallery)

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but note that our sound perception is nearly logarithmic, so it will be very hard to attain "barely audible" sound level.

Comment: You can build a whispering gallery as in St Paul's Cathedral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whispering-gallery_wave or have a couple of concave surfaces https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lC-47_ESeUw

Answer (score 1):

Although your question seem to focus on shaping the room to influence the sound in it you may be interested in this Ted talk. It is about producing nonlinear sound waves that are only audible in certain spots.

http://www.ted.com/talks/woody_norris_invents_amazing_things

So same outcome with different technique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Practically it is never so pronounced like optical foci (cause of characteristic length scales and wavelengths), but it is well-known sound engineering issue in non-rectangular rooms. It generally causes inhomogenous auditory experience and hence it is usually marked as an unwanted phenomenon.